# JavaFX Change list of labels on button click

Tags: button, arraylist, label, javafx-8, settext

I have a list of Labels in a JavaFX app that I've preset with a holder value as such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  lblUserNames.add(new Label("Username goes here"));
}
```

and I'm trying to change the label to display the username on the click of a button by using

```
public void setUsername(int index, String lblUserName) {
   this.lblUserNames.set(index, new Label(lblUserName));
}
```

But it's still showing the holder text instead of updating to show the usernames; and yet when I print out the list of labels, the values have indeed changed.

I had it working before when I had just an array of labels `(Label[])` and could use `".setText(lblUserName)`. I changed it to an ArrayList so that more users can be added and the code wouldn't have to change much, but now I can't use `setText()` anymore.

I've seen similar questions for changing the text for just a Label but the solution is to use `setText()` which won't work with an ArrayList of Labels. Is there any way to update and replace the holder text with the new labels for an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you replace the label in your list, you are not replacing it in the UI. The original label is still shown in the UI. Just call `setText(...)` on the existing label:

```
public void setUsername(int index, String lblUserName) {
   this.lblUserNames.get(index).setText(lblUserName);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! I feel so stupid because before I had it as "this.lblModuleNames[index].setText(lblModuleName)" when it was an array of labels. I didn't realise that the new code wouldn't change it in the UI. Thank you ever so much!